# Как передвинуть границы Text ' а автоматически под размер текста в юнити?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется Text который является дочерним объектом ScrollRect для того чтобы можно было читать весь текст и листать.Как сделать чтобы конец текста совпадал с границы объекта Text.Пробовал Aspect Ratio Fitter и Content Size Fitter.Юнити выдаёт ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]   хотя на родительских объектах ничего нет.И после них текст оказывается в середине родительского объекта.

//Да два три таких Panel можно сделать руками,но когда их число составляет 325 лучше через скрипт и префаб.
Если у вас есть другие варианты реализации этой штуки,пожалуйста пишите    [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно нажать Best Fit у компонента Text, но сам текст будет очень маленьким, потому что на скрине у тебя там не мало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужны 2 операции:

1. `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases` что-бы канвас определил размеры элементов и текста.
2. Теперь ты можеш узнать точную высоту `Text.preferredHeight`, которую хочет текст и установить её для `Content` твоего `ScrollView`.

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class TextContent : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Text _text;
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform _content;

    private void Awake () {
        if (_text != null && _content != null) {
            Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
            _content.sizeDelta = new Vector2(_content.sizeDelta.x, _text.preferredHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял что такое Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases.                                                                                  Но вот решение                               -------------------------------

Comment: public GameObject Text;
    void Start()
    {
         float TextHeight = Text.GetComponent<Text>().preferredHeight;
        RectTransform rect;
        rect = Text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(1,TextHeight);
        rect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(2,-TextHeight/2 );
    }

Comment: Спасибо тебе в любом случае.Очень помог.

Comment: Зачем ты вообще удалил `Viewport` и `Content` в `ScrollView`? Помести текст на `Content`! И у него не нужно менять `anchoredPosition`. До `.ForceUpdate`, `preferredHeight` не посчитан и может быть не правильным, автоматически он посчитается только после первого рендера канваса.

Comment: Объект Text выскакивает на верх с этим скриптом. https://yadi.sk/i/2-ewicXzrRKvrw